# How I can split this with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, split

```
<td class="n_td_brand" width="60">147975<br/>07340778</td>
```

I get this from BeautifulSoup.
Then I have to save this like this

```
list = [147975, 07340778]
```

When I just access with

```
soup.select_one(......).text
```

It shows

```
14797507340778
```

Could you share how to do...Thx in advance.

Comment: Try `soup.select_one(......).contents`, which consist of text nodes and element nodes.

Comment: thanks...it works. so simple..but you great.

Comment: `list(soup.select_one(......).strings)` should also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get_text() will work fine for this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
text = '''<td class="n_td_brand" width="60">147975<br/>07340778</td>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
s = list(map(int, soup.td.get_text(' ').split()))
print(s)
```

**Output**

```
[147975, 07340778]
```

Edit: Modified code to get integer values in list

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_text() with a separator parameter:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_values(html: str) -> list:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    result = soup.find('td', attrs={'class': 'n_td_brand'})

    return list(map(int, result.get_text(separator=' ').split(' ')))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    values = get_values(html="""<td class="n_td_brand" width="60">147975<br/>07340778</td>""")

    print(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my alternative (no splitting) to the answers above.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''
<td class="n_td_brand" width="60">147975<br/>07340778</td>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for e in soup.select('td.n_td_brand'):
    print(list(e.strings))
```